# Showing a periodic orbit for a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $$x''=-f(x,x')x'-x$$ with $f(x,x')<0$ if $x^2+(x')^2<a,$ $f(x,x')>0$ if $x^2+(x')^2>b,$ with $0<a<b$   Show that this system has a periodic orbit.

I am trying to use the follwing theorem:

(Poincaré–Bendixson's Theorem): Let $D$ be a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\phi(t)$ be a
flow on $D$. Suppose that the forward orbit of some $p\in D$ is contained in a compact set
and that $ω( p)$ contains no equilibria. Then $ω( p)$ is a periodic orbit.

But the thing is I have no idea about the function $f$  in order to see if a given point in a connected domain has an equilibrium in a neighborhood of it? I would appreciate any suggestions here.

Comment: i apologize your formala is correct. I will edit

Answer (score 1):

You get for the radius dynamic that
$$
rr'=x'(x''+x)=-f(x,x')(x')^2.
$$
By the further assumptions this means that the annulus $a<r<b$ is a trapping region.

The only thing that might now prevent a limit cycle is the existence of stationary/equilibrium points inside this annulus. However, $x''=x'=0$ implies also $x=0$, so that the origin is the only equilibrium point.